# Incremental update of millions of records

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a table that contains approx 10 million rows. This table is periodically updated (few times a day) by an external process. The table contains information that, if not in the update, should be deleted. Of course, you don't know if its in the update until the update has finished.

Right now, we take the timestamp of when the update began. When the update finishes, anything that has an "updated" value less than the start timestammp is wiped. This works for now, but is problematic when the updater process crashes for whatever value - we have to start again with a new timestamp value.

It seems to be that there must be something more robust as this is a common problem. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a time stamp, use an integer revision number.  Increment it ONLY when you have a complete update, and then delete the elements with out of date revisions.

Comment: +1 - though you might want to update when the purge completes successfully rather than when the updates have completed.  In fact, if you design this carefully, you can probably arrange that updates and purging can run simultaneously.  (Hint - use two sequences instead of one.)

Comment: So for this to work I somewhere store the "next" integer to be used, because it wouldn't be obvious from looking the table whether an update is in progress or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a storage engine that supports transactions, like InnoDb (you're using MySql right?), you can consider using transactions, so if the update process crashes, the modifications are not commited.

Here is the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

We don't know anything about your architecture, and how you do this update (pure SQL, webservice?), but you might already have a transaction management layer.

Comment: A single transaction that updates millions of records is a bad idea from the performance perspective.

Comment: Performance wise or no, the problem described seems to be a perfect fit for a transaction.

Comment: Ignoring performance, or the very real possibility of failure in this case, is a mistake. Especially when the OP made a point of sizing the problem at 10 million rows. Sometimes when you get to millions of objects you have to consider options that are different than when dealing with 10s of objects.

Comment: If the performance of a transaction is likely to be problematic, then this is **by definition** not a "perfect fit".

Comment: Of course a single transaction is not a good idea in that case. But why not processing elements 100000 at a time?

Comment: Transactions are a "perfect fit", in theory.  In *practice*, very very large transactions will stress most database implementations to the edge of their performance.  I would expect a transaction with 10m rows to take a very long time to execute, and if it were to fail, a very long time to roll back.

Comment: @baztone:  he can (and probably should) process elements N at a time, but he still needs to wrap that with the update/expunge semantics he needs.

Comment: @Bastoune - if you are not saying to wrap the updates in one big transaction, then I don't see how "use transactions" solves the OP's issue with the purge phase using the wrong timestamp.

Comment: Sorry,  my bad.  I've read the problem carrefully again and i understood why that didn't fit.

Comment: I do process X rows at a time, but the nature of the data is such that I don't know if something has been updated until the entire operation is complete.